# Memory-effective alternative to select some rows in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I did try `cdr.take(100)`

but the result is

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4357.collectToPython.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 774.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 774.0 (TID 71765, adaijktwrk07.adreach.co, executor 1522): org.apache.spark.memory.SparkOutOfMemory
```

Is there other way to make this process more memory effective?

Comment: that's memory efficient as it can get. Can you share your schema? Do you need to read every field in your schema? Are you certain that the OOM is from this line?

Comment: Error message points out on executor memory, not driver; issue in dataframe transformations, "take(100)" is only shows this issue.

Comment: if you intend to just have few rows of your `DataFrame` , use `limit` - `cdr.limit(50)`